# DICOM Worklist Returning No Match In DCMTK wlmscpfs

Tags: php, dicom, dcmtk

I have setup DCMTK's wlmscpfs on Ubuntu 18.04. The worklist files are converted from dump file to .wl files via dump2dcm. So far the worklist files have been returning successfull matches when queried from several ultrasound machines (Samsung, Siemens). However with another machine, wlmscpfs keeps stating "Information from worklist file ... does not match query" although the search masks contain values that match.

This is the verbose log:

```
Find SCP Request Identifiers:
# Dicom-Data-Set
(0008,0020) DA (no value available)
(0008,0050) SH (no value available)
(0008,0080) LO (no value available)
(0008,0081) ST (no value available)
(0008,0082) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1)
  (fffe,e000) na (Item with undefined length #=4)
    (0008,0100) SH (no value available)
    (0008,0102) SH (no value available)
    (0008,0103) SH (no value available)
    (0008,0104) LO (no value available)
  (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem)
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)
(0008,0090) PN (no value available)
(0008,0092) ST (no value available)
(0008,0094) SH (no value available)
(0008,1080) LO (no value available)
(0008,1084) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1)
  (fffe,e000) na (Item with undefined length #=4)
    (0008,0100) SH (no value available)
    (0008,0102) SH (no value available)
    (0008,0103) SH (no value available)
    (0008,0104) LO (no value available)
  (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem)
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)
(0008,1110) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1)
  (fffe,e000) na (Item with undefined length #=2)
    (0008,1150) UI (no value available)
    (0008,1155) UI (no value available)
  (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem)
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)
(0008,1120) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1)
  (fffe,e000) na (Item with undefined length #=2)
    (0008,1150) UI (no value available)
    (0008,1155) UI (no value available)
  (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem)
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)
(0008,1125) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=0)
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)
(0010,0010) PN (no value available)
(0010,0020) LO (no value available)
(0010,0021) LO (no value available)
(0010,0030) DA (no value available)
(0010,0032) TM (no value available)
(0010,0040) CS (no value available)
(0010,0050) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1)
  (fffe,e000) na (Item with undefined length #=4)
    (0008,0100) SH (no value available)
    (0008,0102) SH (no value available)
    (0008,0103) SH (no value available)
    (0008,0104) LO (no value available)
  (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem)
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)
(0010,1000) LO (no value available)
(0010,1001) PN (no value available)
(0010,1005) PN (no value available)
(0010,1010) AS (no value available)
(0010,1020) DS (no value available)
(0010,1030) DS (no value available)
(0010,1040) LO (no value available)
(0010,1060) PN (no value available)
(0010,1080) LO (no value available)
(0010,1081) LO (no value available)
(0010,1090) LO (no value available)
(0010,2000) LO (no value available)
(0010,2110) LO (no value available)
(0010,2150) LO (no value available)
(0010,2152) LO (no value available)
(0010,2154) SH (no value available)
(0010,2160) SH (no value available)
(0010,2180) SH (no value available)
(0010,21a0) CS (no value available)
(0010,21b0) LT (no value available)
(0010,21c0) US (no value available)
(0010,21d0) DA (no value available)
(0010,21f0) LO (no value available)
(0010,4000) LT (no value available)
(0020,000d) UI (no value available)
(0032,1032) PN (no value available)
(0032,1033) LO (no value available)
(0032,1060) LO (no value available)
(0032,1064) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1)
  (fffe,e000) na (Item with undefined length #=4)
    (0008,0100) SH (no value available)
    (0008,0102) SH (no value available)
    (0008,0103) SH (no value available)
    (0008,0104) LO (no value available)
  (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem)
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)
(0038,0004) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=0)
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)
(0038,0008) CS (no value available)
(0038,0010) LO (no value available)
(0038,0011) LO (no value available)
(0038,0016) LO (no value available)
(0038,0020) DA (no value available)
(0038,0021) TM (no value available)
(0038,0050) LO (no value available)
(0038,0300) LO (no value available)
(0038,0400) LO (no value available)
(0038,0500) LO (no value available)
(0038,4000) LT (no value available)
(0040,0100) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1)
  (fffe,e000) na (Item with undefined length #=16)
    (0008,0060) CS (no value available)
    (0032,1070) LO (no value available)
    (0040,0001) AE (no value available)
    (0040,0002) DA [20201001]
    (0040,0003) TM (no value available)
    (0040,0004) DA (no value available)
    (0040,0005) TM (no value available)
    (0040,0006) PN (no value available)
    (0040,0007) LO (no value available)
    (0040,0008) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1)
      (fffe,e000) na (Item with undefined length #=4)
        (0008,0100) SH (no value available)
        (0008,0102) SH (no value available)
        (0008,0103) SH (no value available)
        (0008,0104) LO (no value available)
      (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem)
    (fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)
    (0040,0009) SH (no value available)
    (0040,0010) SH (no value available)
    (0040,0011) SH (no value available)
    (0040,0012) LO (no value available)
    (0040,0020) CS (no value available)
    (0040,0400) LT (no value available)
  (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem)
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)
(0040,1001) SH (no value available)
(0040,1002) LO (no value available)
(0040,1003) SH (no value available)
(0040,1004) LO (no value available)
(0040,1005) LO (no value available)
(0040,1006) SH (no value available)
(0040,1007) SH (no value available)
(0040,1008) LO (no value available)
(0040,1009) SH (no value available)
(0040,1010) PN (no value available)
(0040,1400) LT (no value available)
(0040,2001) LO (no value available)
(0040,2004) DA (no value available)
(0040,2005) TM (no value available)
(0040,2008) PN (no value available)
(0040,2009) SH (no value available)
(0040,2010) SH (no value available)
(0040,2016) LO (no value available)
(0040,2017) LO (no value available)
(0040,2400) LT (no value available)
(0040,3001) LO (no value available)

Checking the search mask
  - Unsupported (sequence) attribute (InstitutionCodeSequence) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (ReferringPhysicianAddress) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (ReferringPhysicianTelephoneNumbers) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (sequence) attribute (AdmittingDiagnosesCodeSequence) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (sequence) attribute (ReferencedVisitSequence) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (PatientBirthTime) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (sequence) attribute (PatientInsurancePlanCodeSequence) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (PatientBirthName) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (PatientAge) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (PatientMotherBirthName) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (BranchOfService) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (RETIRED_MedicalRecordLocator) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (CountryOfResidence) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (RegionOfResidence) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (PatientTelephoneNumbers) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (Occupation) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (PatientReligiousPreference) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (sequence) attribute (ReferencedPatientAliasSequence) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (VisitStatusID) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (RouteOfAdmissions) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (AdmittingDate) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (AdmittingTime) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (PatientInstitutionResidence) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (VisitComments) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (RETIRED_PlacerOrderNumberProcedure) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.
  - Unsupported (non-sequence) attribute (RETIRED_FillerOrderNumberProcedure) encountered in the search mask.
    This attribute will not be existent in any result dataset.

Expanded Find SCP Request Identifiers:
# Dicom-Data-Set
# Used TransferSyntax: Little Endian Explicit
(0008,0020) DA (no value available)                     #   0, 0 StudyDate
(0008,0050) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 AccessionNumber
(0008,0080) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 InstitutionName
(0008,0081) ST (no value available)                     #   0, 0 InstitutionAddress
(0008,0090) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ReferringPhysicianName
(0008,1080) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 AdmittingDiagnosesDescription
(0008,1110) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1)     # u/l, 1 ReferencedStudySequence
  (fffe,e000) na (Item with undefined length #=2)         # u/l, 1 Item
    (0008,1150) UI (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ReferencedSOPClassUID
    (0008,1155) UI (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ReferencedSOPInstanceUID
  (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem)                   #   0, 0 ItemDelimitationItem
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)               #   0, 0 SequenceDelimitationItem
(0008,1120) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1)     # u/l, 1 ReferencedPatientSequence
  (fffe,e000) na (Item with undefined length #=2)         # u/l, 1 Item
    (0008,1150) UI (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ReferencedSOPClassUID
    (0008,1155) UI (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ReferencedSOPInstanceUID
  (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem)                   #   0, 0 ItemDelimitationItem
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)               #   0, 0 SequenceDelimitationItem
(0010,0010) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientName
(0010,0020) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientID
(0010,0021) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 IssuerOfPatientID
(0010,0030) DA (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientBirthDate
(0010,0040) CS (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientSex
(0010,1000) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 RETIRED_OtherPatientIDs
(0010,1001) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 OtherPatientNames
(0010,1020) DS (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientSize
(0010,1030) DS (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientWeight
(0010,1040) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientAddress
(0010,1080) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 MilitaryRank
(0010,2000) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 MedicalAlerts
(0010,2110) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 Allergies
(0010,2160) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 EthnicGroup
(0010,21a0) CS (no value available)                     #   0, 0 SmokingStatus
(0010,21b0) LT (no value available)                     #   0, 0 AdditionalPatientHistory
(0010,21c0) US (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PregnancyStatus
(0010,21d0) DA (no value available)                     #   0, 0 LastMenstrualDate
(0010,4000) LT (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientComments
(0020,000d) UI (no value available)                     #   0, 0 StudyInstanceUID
(0032,1032) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 RequestingPhysician
(0032,1033) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 RequestingService
(0032,1060) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 RequestedProcedureDescription
(0032,1064) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1)     # u/l, 1 RequestedProcedureCodeSequence
  (fffe,e000) na (Item with undefined length #=4)         # u/l, 1 Item
    (0008,0100) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 CodeValue
    (0008,0102) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 CodingSchemeDesignator
    (0008,0103) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 CodingSchemeVersion
    (0008,0104) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 CodeMeaning
  (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem)                   #   0, 0 ItemDelimitationItem
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)               #   0, 0 SequenceDelimitationItem
(0038,0010) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 AdmissionID
(0038,0011) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 RETIRED_IssuerOfAdmissionID
(0038,0050) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 SpecialNeeds
(0038,0300) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 CurrentPatientLocation
(0038,0500) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientState
(0040,0100) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1)     # u/l, 1 ScheduledProcedureStepSequence
  (fffe,e000) na (Item with undefined length #=16)        # u/l, 1 Item
    (0008,0060) CS (no value available)                     #   0, 0 Modality
    (0032,1070) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 RequestedContrastAgent
    (0040,0001) AE (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ScheduledStationAETitle
    (0040,0002) DA [20201001]                               #   8, 1 ScheduledProcedureStepStartDate
    (0040,0003) TM (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ScheduledProcedureStepStartTime
    (0040,0004) DA (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ScheduledProcedureStepEndDate
    (0040,0005) TM (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ScheduledProcedureStepEndTime
    (0040,0006) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ScheduledPerformingPhysicianName
    (0040,0007) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ScheduledProcedureStepDescription
    (0040,0008) SQ (Sequence with undefined length #=1)     # u/l, 1 ScheduledProtocolCodeSequence
      (fffe,e000) na (Item with undefined length #=4)         # u/l, 1 Item
        (0008,0100) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 CodeValue
        (0008,0102) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 CodingSchemeDesignator
        (0008,0103) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 CodingSchemeVersion
        (0008,0104) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 CodeMeaning
      (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem)                   #   0, 0 ItemDelimitationItem
    (fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)               #   0, 0 SequenceDelimitationItem
    (0040,0009) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ScheduledProcedureStepID
    (0040,0010) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ScheduledStationName
    (0040,0011) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ScheduledProcedureStepLocation
    (0040,0012) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PreMedication
    (0040,0020) CS (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ScheduledProcedureStepStatus
    (0040,0400) LT (no value available)                     #   0, 0 CommentsOnTheScheduledProcedureStep
  (fffe,e00d) na (ItemDelimitationItem)                   #   0, 0 ItemDelimitationItem
(fffe,e0dd) na (SequenceDelimitationItem)               #   0, 0 SequenceDelimitationItem
(0040,1001) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 RequestedProcedureID
(0040,1002) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ReasonForTheRequestedProcedure
(0040,1003) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 RequestedProcedurePriority
(0040,1004) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PatientTransportArrangements
(0040,1005) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 RequestedProcedureLocation
(0040,1008) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ConfidentialityCode
(0040,1009) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ReportingPriority
(0040,1010) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 NamesOfIntendedRecipientsOfResults
(0040,1400) LT (no value available)                     #   0, 0 RequestedProcedureComments
(0040,2001) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 RETIRED_ReasonForTheImagingServiceRequest
(0040,2004) DA (no value available)                     #   0, 0 IssueDateOfImagingServiceRequest
(0040,2005) TM (no value available)                     #   0, 0 IssueTimeOfImagingServiceRequest
(0040,2008) PN (no value available)                     #   0, 0 OrderEnteredBy
(0040,2009) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 OrderEntererLocation
(0040,2010) SH (no value available)                     #   0, 0 OrderCallbackPhoneNumber
(0040,2016) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 PlacerOrderNumberImagingServiceRequest
(0040,2017) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 FillerOrderNumberImagingServiceRequest
(0040,2400) LT (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ImagingServiceRequestComments
(0040,3001) LO (no value available)                     #   0, 0 ConfidentialityConstraintOnPatientDataDescription

=============================
Determining matching records from worklist files
=============================
Worklist Database Files:
/var/www/html/clinicsysmini/iix/mwl/intelsyswl/mwl_161_191.wl
=============================
DcmMetaInfo::checkAndReadPreamble() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Explicit"
DcmDataset::read() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Explicit"
Checking whether worklist file /var/www/html/clinicsysmini/iix/mwl/intelsyswl/mwl_161_191.wl is complete
Checking whether dataset is complete ...
Information from worklist file /var/www/html/clinicsysmini/iix/mwl/intelsyswl/mwl_161_191.wl does not match query
Matching results: 0 matching records found in worklist files
```

This is the dump file content before converted to .wl file by dump2dcm:

```
   (0008,0005) CS [ISO_IR 100]           #   0, 0 CharacterSet\r\n
   (0008,0050) SH [vn123]         #   0, 0 AccessionNumber\r\n
   (0008,0090) PN [docname]            #   0, 0 ReferringPhysicianName\r\n
   (0008,1030) LO [vn123]         #   0, 0 StudyDescription\r\n
   (0008,1080) LO []                     #   0, 0 AdmittingDiagnosesDescription\r\n
   (0010,0010) PN [name]          #   0, 0 PatientName\r\n
   (0010,0020) LO [id]            #   0, 0 PatientID\r\n
   (0010,0030) DA [dob]             #   0, 0 PatientBirthDate\r\n
   (0010,0040) CS [sex]             #   0, 0 PatientSex\r\n
   (0010,1020) DS []              #   0, 0 PatientSize\r\n
   (0010,1030) DS []              #   0, 0 PatientWeight\r\n
   (0010,2000) LO []                     #   0, 0 MedicalAlerts\r\n
   (0010,2110) LO []                     #   0, 0 Allergies\r\n
   (0010,21c0) US []                     #   0, 0 PregnancyStatus\r\n
   (0010,21d0) DA []          #   0, 0 LastMenstrualDate\r\n
   (0010,4000) LT [vn123]         #   0, 0 PatientComments\r\n
   (0020,000D) UI [123.1]  #   0, 0 StudyInstanceUID\r\n
   (0032,1032) PN []            #   0, 0 RequestingPhysician\r\n
   (0032,1060) LO []          #   0, 0 RequestedProcedureDescription\r\n
   (0038,0050) LO []                     #   0, 0 SpecialNeeds\r\n
   (0038,0500) LO []                     #   0, 0 PatientState\r\n
   (0008,1110) SQ                        # u/l, 1 ReferencedStudySequence\r\n
    (fffe,e000) -                        # u/l, 1 Item\r\n
       (0008,1150) UI [1.2.3.4]          #   0, 0 ReferencedSOPClassUID\r\n
       (0008,1155) UI [100.118.116.2005.2.1.1143729853.921.1]   #   0, 0 ReferencedSOPInstanceUID\r\n
     (fffe,e00d) -                       #   0, 0 ItemDelimitationItem\r\n
   (fffe,e0dd) -                         #   0, 0 SequenceDelimitationItem\r\n
   (0008,1120) SQ                        # u/l, 1 ReferencedPatientSequence\r\n
     (fffe,e000) -                       # u/l, 1 Item\r\n
       (0008,1150) UI [1.2.3.4.5]        #   0, 0 ReferencedSOPClassUID\r\n
       (0008,1155) UI [100.118.116.2005.2.1.1143729853.921.3]                 #   0, 0 ReferencedSOPInstanceUID\r\n
     (fffe,e00d) -                       #   0, 0 ItemDelimitationItem\r\n
   (fffe,e0dd) -                         #   0, 0 SequenceDelimitationItem\r\n      
   (0040,0100) SQ                        # 120, 1 ScheduledProcedureStepSequence\r\n
     (fffe,e000) na                       # 112, 1 Item\r\n
       (0008,0060) CS [US]                   #   0, 0 Modality\r\n
       (0040,0001) AE []           #   0, 0 ScheduledStationAETitle\r\n
       (0040,0002) DA [20201001]        #   0, 0 ScheduledProcedureStepStartDate\r\n
       (0040,0003) TM []          #   0, 0 ScheduledProcedureStepStartTime\r\n
       (0040,0006) PN []            #   0, 0 ScheduledPerformingPhysicianName\r\n
       (0040,0007) LO [USG]                  #   0, 0 ScheduledProcedureStepDescription\r\n
       (0040,0008) SQ                        #  40, 1 ScheduledProtocolCodeSequence\r\n
         (fffe,e000) na                       #  32, 1 Item\r\n
           (0008,0100) SH [1]                #   0, 0 CodeValue\r\n
           (0008,0102) SH [1]                    #   0, 0 CodingSchemeDesignator\r\n
           (0008,0103) SH [1]                    #   0, 0 CodingSchemeVersion\r\n
           (0008,0104) LO [1]                    #   0, 0 CodeMeaning\r\n
         (fffe,e00d) na                       #   0, 0 ItemDelimitationItem\r\n
       (fffe,e0dd) na                         #   0, 0 SequenceDelimitationItem\r\n
       (0040,0009) SH [1]                    #   0, 0 ScheduledProcedureStepID\r\n
       (0040,0010) SH []           #   0, 0 Scheduled Station Name\r\n
       (0040,0011) SH []           #   0, 0 Scheduled Procedure Step Location\r\n
       (0040,0012) LO []           #   0, 0 Pre-Medication\r\n
       (0032,1070) LO []           #   0, 0 Requested Contrast Agent\r\n       
       (0040,0400) LT []                     #   0, 0 CommentsOnTheScheduledProcedureStep\r\n
     (fffe,e00d) -                       #   0, 0 ItemDelimitationItem\r\n
   (fffe,e0dd) -                         #   0, 0 SequenceDelimitationItem\r\n
   (0040,1001) SH []  #   0, 0 RequestedProcedureID\r\n
   (0040,1002) LO []                     #   0, 0 ReasonForTheRequestedProcedure\r\n
   (0040,1003) SH []                     #   0, 0 Requested Procedure Priority\r\n
   (0040,1004) SH []
```

(names have been removed from the above codes)

I have referred to the DICOM conformance statement but it says search can be done with empty parameters, that we have tried and still returning 'no match found'.
How do I fix this?

Comment: The only parameter searched is the date, and it is exactly the same. The same file works for another modality that also searches only for the date (Scheduled Procedure Step Start Date 0040,0002)

Comment: Did you check that "/var/www/html/clinicsysmini/iix/mwl/intelsyswl/mwl_161_191.wl" is the correct file? You wrote: "This is the dump file content before converted to .wl file by dump2dcm" - Did you also check the contents of the .wl file with dcmdump?

Comment: Yes, thought of that too, whether it is the correct file. Checked the .wl file in DICOM editor and the correct date is shown under Scheduled Procedure Step Start Date (0040,0002). As the search mask is only by this date, it should have produced a match right?

Answer (score 5):

For the benefit of others, here is the solution:
If the modality sends query field (although empty) and the .wl file does not contain the query field, it returns as no match. In my case, fields (0038,0010) and (0008,0020) where not available in the .wl file, so when the modality sends query with these 2 fields, although empty, wlmscpfs returns as no match. When I added these 2 fields into the .wl files, it returns as match!